# Convert char to date in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am having a table in phpmyadmin named transaction_details where i am having a column named tr_date whose datatype is char(10) and a sample value is '21-02-2016'.

I want to convert that char to date using the following query ---

```
SELECT str_to_date('SUBSTR( tr_date, 1, 2 ),SUBSTR( tr_date, 4, 2 ),SUBSTR(tr_date, 7, 4 )','%d,%m,%Y') FROM transaction_details where tr_id=3;
```

But when i execute the query, it returned me NULL. Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you need those single quotes.  This might be what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT str_to_date(CONCAT_WS(',' SUBSTR(tr_date, 1, 2 ),
                             SUBSTR(tr_date, 4, 2 ),
                             SUBSTR(tr_date, 7, 4 )
                            ), '%d,%m,%Y')
FROM transaction_details
WHERE tr_id = 3;
```

But really, the string operations are unnecessary.  This is the more reasonable solution:

```
SELECT str_to_date(tr_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
FROM transaction_details
WHERE tr_id = 3;
```

Comment: great!!!!!!!!!!, your second query helped me to solve my problem. thanks alot.........